# How do I install Jolicloud if I run Ubuntu now?

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, jolicloud

Hey, I really need help here.

Right now I run Ubuntu 10.10, but I have downloaded a Jolicloud .iso but how do i install it? Hope somebody can help me (:

Answer (score 3):

1. Back up. The unicorns will thank you.
2. Follow [these directions](http://help.jolicloud.com/entries/230978-how-do-i-make-jolicloud-my-only-operating-system), but when you get step 4, choose `Install them side by side, choosing between them at startup` instead of `Use the entire disk`. The bar at the top should spawn a slider/draggy that you can drag to allocate how big you want both partitions to be.
3. Continue following the directions.
4. Grab a coffee after you hit the `Install` button. You'll be there a while.
5. Reboot and pull the Jolicloud CD out.

Answer (score 0):

make a bootable USB stick with unetbootin (select .ISO), and boot from it. http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net